# Generate xml from existing xml without one node

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to generate an xml from existing one but remove one node by Id:
My xml is:

```
<PartyList>
  <Party Id="1" In="true" Out="true"/>
  <Party Id="2" In="true" Out="false"/>
  <Party Id="3" In="true" Out="true"/>
</PartyList>
```

and tried to select the node by using the following but cant remove it:

```
xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/PartyList/Party[@Id='3']"));
```

how can I remove it? and is there a better way by using linq to xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing selected element from the `XmlDocument` can be done as follow :

```
xmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/PartyList/Partyx[@Id='3']");
xmlNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xmlNode);
xmlDoc.Save("path_for_the_updated_file.xml");
```

Or using LINQ-to-XML's `XDocument` :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path_to_your_xml_file.xml");
doc.Root
   .Elements("Partyx")
   .First(o => (int)o.Attribute("Id") == 3)
   .Remove();
doc.Save("path_for_the_updated_file.xml");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer... I did it in for loop so can i keep the original xml and save the new xml in a string value

Comment: @user1150331 you can access the string value of the updated XML from `OuterXml` property of `XmlDocument` or by calling `ToString()` on the `XDocument` : `xmlDoc.OuterXml`, or `doc.ToSring()`